# How can I get confluence.pm to add labels

Tags: perl, confluence

I can add a new page with the code below but I've tried to automatically add a label and it just gets ignored. Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so, what I need to do?

```
my $project_page = {
                    space => 'Test',
                    title => 'Test Page',
                    content => $content,
                    parentId => $parent_page->{"id"},
                    label => 'test'
                    };

$wiki->updatePage($project_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be a part of the [XML-RPC spec](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Remote+API+Specification#RemoteAPISpecification-Page). I suggest you use a SOAP client to do this. I like Bob Swift's [Confluence CLI](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/284).

```
confluence --action addLabels --space "Test" --title "Test Page" --labels "test1, test2"
```